# Deleted questions missing purple-tinted background on mobile site

Tags: bug, status-completed, deleted-questions, mobile-web

On the Stack Overflow full site deleted posts are shown with a [purple-tinted background](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22184/what-do-the-colors-on-stack-overflow-mean).  On the mobile site (tested on the iPhone), deleted answers also receive this treatment but deleted questions have a normal white background.

On the mobile site, deleted questions should have the same background as deleted answers.

Here is a sample deleted question that demonstrates the problem (10k link only):

- [How to avoid having capistrano SSH to localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210892/how-to-avoid-having-capistrano-ssh-to-localhost)

Comment: Oh, that's purple? And here all this time I thought it was gray! Time to re-calibrate the monitor on this notebook I suppose...

Comment: @cody XD It's light purple -> pink. OP this is purple: [....](http://phpcode.eu/images/1314615441.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been completed and will go out with the next build.