# Deleted questions from mobile site

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-questions, mobile-web

Possibly related to the solution to [this issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104155/deleted-questions-missing-purple-tinted-background-on-mobile-site), I am able yo see deleted questions (with their tint) in the questions list, despite not having the 10k required to do so. Clicking on them leads to to the deleted question page (which is not mobile-friendly).

I have experienced this both on the home page and when viewing the questions sorted under "newest".

Comment: Which question list (what URL) are you seeing them in?

Comment: It was the Stackoverflow home page, first time I had accessed it since turning on my phone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is a caching issue or something.

Deleted questions *seem* to appear on the main page for a few minutes after deletion. They go away soon, though. How long have you waited? And which list are you talking about? (Main page sorted by xyz, question list sorted by xyz, etc)

Comment: Main page with no sorting.

Comment: @Jim still there? It should go away within 10mins of deletion.

Comment: Also questions sorted by time (newest)